# How to make an inherited virtual function not usable?

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I have an abstract base class which declares a pure virtual function (`virtual method() = 0;`). Some of the inherited classes specialize and use this method but there's one of those inherited classes in which I don't want to make this method usable. How do I do it? Is making it private the only choice?

Comment: Make it private in which class(es)?  Making it private only in the problem class won't stop it being invoked when called against a pointer to a base class instance.

Comment: If calling `method()` on this class doesn't make sense, should it really derive from this base class in the first place?  It seems that this is a design flaw

Comment: As GuyGreer says, this seems like a design flaw. See [Liskov substition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @GuyGreer the base class is a polyphormic class, and I want to use pointers to that class to manipulate objects to derived classes. When the pointer is pointing to an object from a class that has that method usable I want to being able to use that method, but when the object points to an object of this specific class, it should throw an error when I try to use that method. Is it possible?

Comment: [Here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/146061/105930) is my code. The problematic class is `Token::Symbol`. All `Token` classes inherit from `Token::Base` and I'm going to manipulate `Token::Base` pointers, and that's why `Token::Base` has the method as a pure virtual function (the method is `Value::Ptr to_value()`). However, `Token::Symbol` has no corresponding `Value::Symbol` class to be converted to, and that's why I want to make `Token::Symbol::to_value` unusable. Hope this explains it a little better.

Comment: Why is there no `Value::Symbol`?  I don't know your project in depth but it seems to me that a `Token::Symbol`'s value type should be `Value::Symbol`

Comment: @GuyGreer Symbols are what tells the parser "here an expression starts", "here a block ends". After parsing, all Tokens will be converted to Values, but there will be no Symbols in the newly created Abstract Syntax Tree because their only purpose was to construct it.

Comment: How about changing the return type of `to_value` to return an `(std|boost)::optional` and change the logic of the code calling that function to handle the case when some tokens don't return values?

Comment: @GuyGreer throwing is okay, it's only to prevent myself to accidentally call a Token::Symbol's to_value during parsing, but after writing it and making sure that I don't do that I could even replace `{ throw /*something*/ }` with a simple `{}`. That's why I would have preferred a compile time error, but it's the same thing.

Comment: This cannot be enforced at compile time. Consider this function: `Token::Symbol get_value(Token::Base* base) { return base->to_value(); }`. Should this generate a compile time error? It depends on what `base` is, which is not known at compile time.

Comment: So like Java, which throws a `NotImplementedException`? This is very bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could throw that will make tacking where it is called easier.

```
void method() override { throw /* whatever */ ; }
```

Dynamic polymorphism is a runtime property. Hence a runtime error. If you look after something that will trigger at compile time, you need static polymorphism.

```
template<typename Child>
struct Parent {
    void callMe() {
        static_cast<Child*>(this)->callMeImpl();
    }
};

struct SomeChild : Parent<SomeChild> {

};
```

Now, if you try to call `callMe` form the parent that is extended by `SomeChild`, it will be a compile time error.

You can also hold pointer to the parent just like dynamic polymorphism, as the parent will call the child function

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with a static assertion?

Comment: @user6245072 no, `static_assert` only works at compile time and it would mean that you could never compile your class and never get your program running.  For runtime polymorphism (ie, virtual functions and inheritance) you need a runtime error

Comment: Alright. That was the way I handled it in the previous versions of this project (by throwing) anyway, so I guess I will use this.

Comment: See my edits if you want static_assert along with static polymorphism.

Comment: `parent->callMe()` won't be a compile-time error, it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: How is this polymorphism? Each child has a unique parent: `Parent<Child1>`, `Parent<Child2>`, etc. There is no common `Parent` class with multiple children.

Comment: It is commonly called *static polymorphism* and uses the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) pattern

Comment: @RaymondChen The base classes all share a common implicit interface so they could be treated the same in a templated function.

Answer (score 0):

> Is making it private the only choice?

No, that's not a choice at all since you can still access the method if it's `public` or `protected` in the base classes.

Other than implementing the method in the class and resorting to run-time failures, there's not a lot you can do. You *could* port the whole thing to templates and use *static polymorphism* which, with further trickey, you could contrive a *compile-time* failure in certain instances, but that could be design overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could make it a normal virtual function instead of a pure virtual function like this:

```
virtual void method() { /* code */ }
```

If this function is not being used in another class, you will be able to catch that. For example you could warn yourself:

```
virtual void method() { error = true; } //or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said there is no way of enforcing this at compile time. If you are referring to a pointer to a base class there is no way the compiler can know if that pointer is referring to one of the derived classes that *does* implement this method or one that *doesn't*.

So the case will have to be handled at runtime. One option is to just throw an exception. Another option is to introduce a level of indirection so that you can ask your base class if it implements a certain function before you call it.

Say you have a `Base` class with three methods `foo`, `bar` and `doit` and some derived classes do not want to implement `foo` then you could split up the `Base` class into two base classes:

```
class Base1 {
    public:
        virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Base2 {
    public:
        virtual void bar() = 0;
        virtual void doit() = 0;
};
```

Then in places where you are currently using `Base` you instead use a `BaseSource`:

```
class BaseSource {
    public:
        virtual Base1* getBase1() = 0;
        virtual Base2* getBase2() = 0;
};
```

where `getBase1` and `getBase2` can return `nullptr` if a `BaseSource` does not offer that interface:

```
class Derived : public BaseSource, public Base2 {
  public:   
     // don't implement foo();

     // Implemementation of Base2
     void bar() override;
     void doit() override;

     Base1* getBase1() override { return nullptr; } // Doesn't implement Base1
     Base2* getBase2() override { return this; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseSource>> objects;
    objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived>());

    for (auto& o : objects) {
      auto b1 = o->getBase1();
      if (b1)
          b1->foo();
      auto b2 = o->getBase2();
      if (b2)
          b2->bar();
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9AM6NnZXVJT393Q1).